# I want to add a check in database column, so that people who enter data into it should be in capital and trimmed

Tags: sql-server

The situation is: I have a column in a database table where people enter data using SQL scripts directly (without any web page).

I want to put a restriction on that column to ensure if anyone enters data it is trimmed and capitalized, otherwise it should not accept it.

Or it should do it automatically.

Yours sincerely.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one. Replace 'myTableName' with your table name. Replace 'myColumnName' with your column name. NOTE : UpperCaseCheck is the name of the constraint, as well as DataLenCheck.

```
--UpperCaseCheck 

        ALTER TABLE myTableName
            ADD CONSTRAINT UpperCaseCheck CHECK(myColumnName = UPPER(myColumnName) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS);

      -- DataLenCheck constraint  

        ALTER TABLE myTableName
        ADD CONSTRAINT DataLenCheck CHECK(DataLength(myColumnName) = DataLength(Rtrim(LTrim(myColumnName))))

    -- Instead of two constraint, we can use only one

    ALTER TABLE myTableName
    ADD CONSTRAINT UpperCaseCheckAndDataLenCheck CHECK(myColumnName = UPPER(myColumnName) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
    AND DataLength(myColumnName) = DataLength(LTrim(Rtrim(myColumnName))))
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2017

```
select upper(trim(@param_name))
```

Older versions

```
select upper(rtrim(ltrim(@param_name)))
```